# Image Magnifiers and Clickable Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-experience, imagemap, magnification

I'm currently using an application that generates large images for organizational maps, unfortunately the content is quite small due to the volume of data being output.  I would like to find a way that allows the user to view segments of the map in an intuitive manner, yet still allow the user to click content inside of the map.

The first thing that came to mind was an image magnifier using something similar to the loupe jQuery plugin.  This works great for magnifying the image, but I can't select content once magnified.  If anyone has any suggestions for possible solutions to this issue I would greatly appreciate the help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might try Etalage: http://frique.me/demos/etalage/ -- if you click on the image, the link works (triggers the javascript alert), almost no other image zoomer seems to do that.

I'm trying to find something that returns the coordinates on a click, so I can ask users to zoom and and find things within a picture, and then I'll have the coordinates to crop the picture to extract the items they've found.  But I haven't found a script that does that yet, either.